# Worker node limit in Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a plan to use Kubernetes in Google Cloud as a production stage.

However, I found [this document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing#limits) explaining that there is a limitation at 250 worker nodes in a group.

> In a GKE cluster, an internal forwarding rule points to all the nodes in the cluster. Each node in the cluster is a backend VM for the ILB. The maximum number of backend VMs for an ILB is 250, regardless of how the VMs are associated with instance groups. So the maximum number of nodes in a GKE cluster with an ILB is 250. If you have autoscaling enabled for your cluster, you must ensure that autoscaling does not scale your cluster beyond 250 nodes.

Could you explain the above to me?

Should I create a second and third cluster, in case our worker nodes reach ~250.

I will be using the load balancer in the front of our services.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand "Should i create the second, third cluster, in case our worker node reach ~250 worker node."  GKE clusters have node pools and each node pool is group of Virtual Machines hosted on Compute Engine. If your design permits scaling up to 250 GCE VMs, you will hit an upper hard limit with ILB. In that case, you are correct, you will need to create another GKE cluster.   There are many other considerations you should look into building your GKE cluster : 
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/scalability#understanding_limits